# On the need for __init__() function in Python class

Tags: python, class

I have a very basic question about why I need `__init__` in declaring a class in Python.

For example, in [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp), an example was introduced

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

p1 = Person("John", 36)

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
```

But the above example requires a series of arguments as `("John", 36)`. When the number of arguments is large, they may be error-prone in the input. I can use `*args`, but it also requires the order of argument. If I just provide a default value of the `name` and `age`, and modify in need, will it simplify the practice? For example

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    
class Person2:
  name = "John"
  age = 36    
  
class Person3:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.name = args[0]
    self.age = args[1]
      

p1 = Person("John", 36)
print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)

p2 = Person2()
print(p2.name)
print(p2.age)


p2.name = "Mike"
p2.age = 35
print(p2.name)
print(p2.age)


p3 = Person3("John", 36)
print(p3.name)
print(p3.age)
```

`Person2` is perhaps the simplest. But, will `Person2` be a good practice?

Comment: For data "structs", look into `dataclass` from the `dataclasses` package from the standard library. If you plan for more complex functionality you should stick with a conventional implementation that includes *named* arguments and an `__init__` (in other words, don't ever do `Person3`).

Comment: What you propose in the question isn't actually any less error-prone. It just means you silently get the wrong attribute values if you screw up, instead of getting an error message. Error messages are better than silent failures. They let you know about the problem and help you fix it.

Comment: When the number of arguments is large, it probably means you should define some more types: `Foo(Bar(a, b), Baz(c, d)` instead of `Foo(a, b, c, d)`, for example.

Comment: @chepner do you mean nested class?

Comment: No, that's just composition. Nested classes are rarely used in Python.

Comment: @chepner Do you mean `Bar` and `Baz` are other functions? sorry I searched over `composition`, seems too advanced to me.

Comment: Composition just means using types in other types. It's unlikely that all the arguments need to be passed directly to `Foo`. For example, you can define a line with 2 points, where each point has an x- and a y-coordinate. Instead of `Line(x1, y1, x2, y2)`, define a `Point` class to represent the points and have `Line` take two instances of `Point` as arguments, not 4 numbers: `Line(Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2)). There's less room for error when any given value requires fewer arguments to define.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read into the difference of `class` and an `instance` of a class: `Person2` will not fly as every person would be the same. You use the class here basically as a namespace without further usage.

`Person3` is basically a bad version of `Person1`.

`Person1` will be ok and not error prone as you can also pass the arguments as keyword arguments (`Person(name=..., age=...)`.

You may also have a look at `dataclasses` as they remove this kind of boilerplate: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html